# accessing a file in /sdcard/udisk returns permission denied. file.exists() return false all the time

Tags: java, android, sdk, permissions

I'm trying to check (with java code) if a file under /sdcard/udisk exists and if yes, then I'll copy it to other place where I need it.
when I run ls -l on the directory i see it's permissions are weird:

```
d---rwxr-x  4 1000 1015    4096 Jan 1 1970 udisk
```

and I'm writing my code in the system server which doesn't have root permissions it has 1000.

anyway I don't know what to do in here, how can I gain permissions for that? I tried to change permissions for /mnt/sdcard/udisk by hand chmod 777... didn't help.

```
File udisk = new File("/sdcard/udisk");
if(udisk.exists()) {
    do something
} else {
    do else
}
```

exists() always returns false, even though on adb shell you see the folder does exist.

Comment: do you have a rooted phone?

Comment: it's not a exactly a phone, it's a system that runs android. and I don't need emulator, the code is inside the system server. meaning I'm changing the os code.

Comment: As per You Comment:--it's not a exactly a phone and I don't need emulator..so where did u test ur app ?

Comment: it's not really an App.. I'm writing a system service.. inside the os code.

Comment: How are you accessing `/sdcard/udisk`? Post the code.

Comment: What is this directory, and who created it?  What is the filesystem type and what are the mount flags?

Comment: see above for the code. this directory is created by the file system when you insert a disk on key or sdcard externally to phone, or android system board.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the prior permission to access to sdcard

-> open the manifest file and paste the below code
 uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: the code sits under /android/framework/base/ which doesn't have manifest files.

Comment: Not relevant - please see the comments.

Comment: not relevant to my question. but anyway just for the knowledge, this permission (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) is not yet enforced and all apps still have access to external storage with no need for permission. though it is defined. in later android versions it will be applied. anyway, my question is not for an app

Answer (score 0):

add this code before starting application tag in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Not relevant, please see the comments

Comment: my code is inside the android framework, and not an application. this is what he means